# SAS - Cumulative sum with date range and conditions

Tags: sas

The following is an example of the data I have

| startdate | enddate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2010 | 2/2/2020 | 10 |
| 1/5/2011 | 2/3/2015 | 10 |
| 1/3/2012 | 2/2/2023 | 10 |
| 1/4/2013 | 2/2/2014 | 10 |
| 5/5/2015 | 2/2/2028 | 10 |
| 1/6/2016 | 2/2/2032 | 10 |

I want to calculate the sum of all existing amounts as of each start date so it should look like this:

| startdate | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2010 | 10 |
| 1/5/2011 | 20 |
| 1/3/2012 | 30 |
| 1/4/2013 | 40 |
| 5/5/2015 | 30 |
| 1/6/2016 | 40 |

How do I do this in SAS?

Essentially what I want to do is for each of the start dates, calculate the cumulative sum of any amounts that haven't expired. So for the first four dates, it is just a running cumulative sum because none of the amounts have expired. But at 5/5/2015, two of the previous amounts have expired hence a cumulative sum of 30. Same for the last date, where the same two have previously expired and you have the additional amount as of 1/6/2016 therefore 40.

Comment: Can you explain the logic in more detail? It initially looked like a running sum, but that's not the case, since it drops back to 30. Additionally, it doesn't look to be a sum during the period (start/end). It also doesn't look like it can be grouped by start dates as each start date is different.  So I'm not sure how your logically arrived at those amounts?

Comment: Also, is the 5th line in the "want" data set supposed to have a date of 5/5/2015 or 1/5/2015? Ideally your example is a fully reproducible example, ie we put in that input and get the shown output.

Comment: The input of 1/5/2015 was actually an error which I've changed. Essentially what I want to do is for each of the start dates, calculate the cumulative sum of any amounts that haven't expired. So for the first four dates, it is just a running cumulative sum because none of the amounts have expired. But at 5/5/2015, two of the previous amounts have expired hence a cumulative sum of 30. Same for the last date, where the same two have previously expired and you have the additional amount as of 1/6/2016 therefore 40.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is with a self-join via Proc SQL:

```sql
proc sql;
    create table out_dset as
    select a.startdate, sum(a.amount) as amount
    from in_dset as a left join in_dset as b
    on a.startdate >= b.startdate and a.startdate < b.enddate
    group by a.startdate
    order by a.startdate;
quit;
```

For each observation in the original dataset, this code will find observations in the same dataset that meet the date range criteria and will sum up the amount column.

You can change the second comparison operator from `<` to `<=` if you want to include situations when a previous amount expired on the same date as a given startdate.